# Data table format for Time

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have a data table that I am using to fill a data grid.

I am filling the table with data from a database. One of the columns is "Start Class" which needs to be a time but the "GetType(Date)" gives the date as well.

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionPath)
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Groups"

        daGroups = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
        daGroups.Fill(dsGroups, "strSQL")

        Table.Columns.Add("Class Start", GetType(Date))

        For Each Row In dsGroups.Tables("strSQL").Rows
            Table.Rows.Add(Row.Item(0))
        Next

        dtTable = Table
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's better to preserve datatype in data containers and format it once it's displayed in the view.  I'm not sure if that'll be the case for you,  you can use

```
date.ToString("hh:mm")
```

to format in code or

```
<asp:Label id="lblDate" runat="server" Text="<%# Bind('data.date', '{0:hh:mm}') %>" />
```

for  asp pages

not sure if that'll help you

Comment: I'm not sure where I would put that piece of code in? Would it be placed in the 
    GetType(Date.Tostring("hh:mm"))
or defined somewhere else?

Comment: how do u render the data or read the data?　you should put it there, so you can keep database date as object, but format it when rending.  Do u use asp.net? or Form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I use Form.

Comment: I assume you bind the data to a datagrid?  try this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx, set the format = "hh:mm";

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTime.ToString("hh:mm")` to get only time from your `DateTime` instance, For more Info [Visit this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)